# Is there a function continuous on $R$, such that $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ iff $f(x+1)\in\mathbb{R\setminus Q}$?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

I am given the following question:

> Is there a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, continuous on $R$, such that $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ iff $f(x+1)\in \mathbb{R \setminus Q}$?

I think it cannot exist because the intermediate value property would pop out numbers from $\mathbb{R}$ until I would have two rationals between two irrational numbers instead of one. I thought about having two sequences that converge at the same $x$ but I don't know how to go further with this ideea, as I don`t know how to give a rigurous formalisation of that ideea of obtaining that two numbers.

I thought about Dirichlet's function and it can be ''connected'' to our function, but I do not see how to link continuity to a property of Dirichlet's function so to obtain a result.

Any help would be warmly welcomed.

Comment: I don't understand why you would be concerned with having "two rationals between two irrational numbers instead of one". Nothing says there's *only* one, and in fact there are infinitely many rational numbers between any two given irrational numbers.

Comment: Can you write down a continuous function on $[0,1]$ with $f(0)\in\Bbb Q$ and $f(1)\notin\Bbb Q$?

Comment: Lee Mosher: I thought of something else but, again, it isn`t rigurous enough and as I can see I was not able to explain what I thought of. I think that detail can be ignored.

Comment: OK, that's one idea. However, if I iterate that, $f(1)=\pi$ and $f(1+1)=2\pi\notin\Bbb Q$. Can you think of a different function so that $f(2)$ will again be rational? Ah, but my idea only gives $f(x)\in\Bbb Q\implies f(x+1)\notin\Bbb Q$, not $f(x)\notin\Bbb Q\implies f(x+1)\in\Bbb Q$.  So your original instinct is, I believe, correct.

Comment: I think I wanted to say $f(x)=x\pi$ because otherwise $f(0)=\pi$ and $f(1)=1+\pi$ and both would be irrational. Can you iterate it if it is defined on $[0,1]$? Hm, also, I thought of a function like that you required but I can`t think of any that would just come back to bein rational after another iteration and be continuous, that detail has the key I think but I don't see it right now.

Comment: What's the relevance of continuity? If $f(0)=a$ and $f(1)=b\ne a$, what does continuity now tell you?

Comment: Well, nothing as of that example you gave. It can be discontinuous as well as continuous. But there must be some connection to the problem. Anyway, let's continue on the examples given. Are you trying to tell me there is no way to construct an iterative function that just switches beetween rational/ irational values?

Comment: By the way: OMG I realised who you are. I partly used your course in studying differential geometry. Thank you for writing it!!!

Comment: $f(x)+f(x+1)$ is irrational for all $x$ thus not continuous. Maybe more fun when looking at $g:\Bbb{Q\to R}$ having the same properties $g(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ iff $g(x+1)\in \mathbb{R \setminus Q}$

Comment: reuns: Thank you!!! I think I'll try to answer it and see what I get. Would you assist me after posting it? Let's see.

Comment: @reuns Why can't $f(x)+f(x+1)$ be constant?

Comment: @TedShifrin Right, $f(x)-f(x+1)$ has the same properties, so they must be both constant, a contradiction

Comment: @reuns that would make our $f(x)$ a constant function by summation and division by 2. Hmm...

Comment: @reuns: Yeah, just need the extra work. It also follows immediately from countability/uncountability issues.

Comment: @TedShifrin what issues? Please develop, I am curious.

Comment: @TedShifrin With my method we can replace $\Bbb{Q}$ by any dense subgroup, can you construct one making your countability argument fail?

Comment: @reuns: Interesting; if it's finitely generated, it'll still be countable. I suppose there must be an uncountable one whose complement is uncountable; then my argument fails. Ugh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as reuns( it's the name of an account) has observed and told me: the basic ideea is to observe that if $f(x)\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x+1)\in\Bbb R\backslash\Bbb Q$ for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$, then $f(x)+f(x+1)\in\Bbb R\backslash\Bbb Q$, and because the finite sum of continuous function is a continuos function and this sum is not continuous, we get the answer to the question, that a function with that property does not exist.

Comment: Oops. I'll ask you the same question I just asked above. Why can't $f(x)+f(x+1)$ be constant? Indeed, my original solution had that.

Comment: we would have that $f(x)+f(x+1)=f(x+1)+f(x+2)$ and so $f(x)=f(x+2)=f(x+4)=f(x+6)=...$ and $f(x+1)=f(x+3)=f(x+5)=...$ and one would be rational, another irrational and I don't think this would be a contionus function.

Comment: Why can't we take a function that is periodic with period $2$ that satisfies $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)\notin\Bbb Q$ (and $f(x+1)=f(1)-f(x)$ for $x\in [1,2]$?

Comment: The problem as I have read it does not specify if $x$ is fixed or not, but I think it is intended for every $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Otherwise I see no use for continuity.

Comment: Of course. It is supposed to hold for all $x\in\Bbb R$. Where did I fix $x$?

Comment: Ok, I follow, but what should happen to the rest of $x$, other that those in $[0,2]$?

Comment: We already agreed the function would be periodic with period 2.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define g(x)=f(x)+f(x+1) and h(x)=f(x)-f(x+1), x in R. Then both g and h are continuous on R and assume only irrotational values. So both g and h are constant. Adding these two functions, 2f(x)= g(x)+h(x), a constant as both g and h are constants. Again if f is constant then it does not satisfy the given conditions. Thus there does not exist a continuous function satisfying the given condition.